# curl script to extract tar files

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I have a curl script that i use to get read files from a url.  I now need to extract the tar files after they are downloaded.

```
for file in $(/usr/bin/curl 'https://linktofile.com/yourfile.txt' );
  do
    echo $file;
    /usr/bin/curl -L -J -O "$file";
done;
```

output to the screen is

```
curl: Saved to filename 'your_file_1.tar'
```

How do I extract the file that was saved?
I tried adding `tar -xvf $file` but nothing happens.
How do I get the name of the file that was just saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-J` makes the file's location depend on the `Content-Disposition` header, so you need to retrieve the filename it specifies. You can do so by specifying through `-w` the output of the `curl` command, which you will want to output the filename :

```
for url in $(/usr/bin/curl 'https://linktofile.com/yourfile.txt' ); do
    filename=$(/usr/bin/curl -sLJOw '%{filename_effective}' "$url")
    tar -xvf "$filename"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I don't use bash all that much.

Comment: @user3525290 You're welcome, glad I could help! That wasn't trivial either, I had to look it up.